# Can't load file or assembly after web-deploy

Tags: c#, asp.net, dll, webdeploy

Application is working fine on local machine, but on deploying in server it throws this error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'DevelopDotNet.Compression.DLL' or one
>   of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

**I have already added "DevelopDotNet.Compression.DLL" assembly to references.**

After deploying "DevelopDotNet.Compression.DLL" assembly is present in 'bin' folder.

Comment: Not a programming question, probably more suited to another SE site.

Comment: Keywords here are `or one of its dependencies`. Make sure you copied over any DLL files that `DevelopDotNet` might be dependent on. Also make sure **both** are compiled for either 32-bit, 64-bit or any.

Comment: @kebs: absolutely appropriate for [so]. Where do you think the application _came from_? Was it magic, or did a **developer** ***develop*** it?

Comment: @John Saunders ok, it was just a suggestion, as I didn't see any code involved, thank you.

Comment: @kebs: the code was already developed. Now it's ready to deploy.

Comment: @Icemanind I have tried both 32-bit and 64-bit, but same problem.. it working on local machine without any dependencies, and failed to load on Hosting Server.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, the application was not working on my local machine too. I have a 64 bit OS with Windows 10 installed. Through various workarounds, I have finally able to solve the problem. I have done the following to diagnose the root cause:

1. Downloaded and installed dependency walker to find the associated
   dependencies from [this website](http://www.dependencywalker.com/).
2. Here, I have found that 2 of associated dependencies were missing,
   namely, `msvcr71.dll` and `msvcp71.dll`. So, I have downloaded them
   and put them at `C:\Windows\System32` and `C:\Windows\SysWOW64`.
3. Then, I follow the step-by-step guide from [this website](http://www.dlldownloader.com/msvcp71-dll/).
4. And, finally able to run the application.

Hope, this helps someone who is juggling around the google.